# Calling controller method from Razor page OnGet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, razor, razor-pages

What is the best practice of calling a controller method decorated with for example [HttpGet] or [HttpPost] from a Razor page OnGet in an ASP.NET Core application?

Comment: Is this a controller in the same application?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not specifying that. The controller is in the same project solution in VS.

Comment: So why do you want to call it in a page handler method?

Comment: Come to think of it, perhaps it doesn't make much sense after all. The reason for me asking is that I wanted to make a server side database call from an API controller I had created, but I've learned now that the OnGet page handler method runs on the server and not on the client, and thus there is no reason to not make the database call from the OnGet method.

Comment: I want to confirm with you, is your api controller located in another project? They only belong to the same solution but not the same project?

Comment: For this particular example it is part of the same project.

Answer (score 0):

Your API controller and razor page `OnGet` both will be run on the server if they are part of the same application.

So you do not need to make an API call you can just call the code directly from `OnGet`

The best practice is to create a Service class that contains the shared code so that both methods can call it. Then use dependency injection in the API controller and your Razor page to access the Service class.

[Fundamentals of dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)